# Spring Boot creating an XML endpoint

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot

I have been learning spring-boot for a while and building learning projects step by step. I am currently doing a project, what i am trying to achieve is building a web endpoint which receives an XML data/list as an input and write it to DB.

To make my point clear:

- I have a JMS Queue and a working program that reads the Queue, parse it to defined xml format and publish it to an endpoint.
- My new project is supposed to listen for XML data, parse it based on a predefined class matching the XML structure (i am thinking of defining the structure with a class) and using JPA to persist an instance of the class(parsed XML) to the database.
- Previously i have some experience with basic RESTful web-service projects with GET,POST,DELETE methods.

What i am asking is :

1. Is my above outline feasible
2. I can not find a way to implement parsing of an XML to an Object
3. In the controller class (that's what i've been using for REST) what method do i use as an entry point.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a put or post method in a REST controller that Consumes XML data.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/myRestPath", consumes = "application/xml")
public class MyXmlController{

   @PutMapping
   public void putXmlObject(MyXmlObject myXmlObject){
   // do somthing
   }

}
```